# how to fill combobox with database data java and hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

here is my code:
In dao class
for reading data from DB

```
    public static List<Animals> read() {
    List<Animal> a = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    Transaction tran = null;
    Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        tran = session.beginTransaction();
        a = session.createQuery("from Animal").list();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return a;
}
```

and jframe:

```
List<Animal> animals = AnimalDao.read();

public void addCombo(){
for(Animal a : animals){ combo.addItem(a);}
```

As a result my comboBox displays things like: model.Animals@5a0ffc79
Can you help me figure it out whats missing?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By default, when using objects (rather than strings) in a JcomboBox, the value that's being displayed in the combo box will be the `toString()` method of the object. So the simple option will be to implement `toString()` on your `Animal` class with the value you want to display.

Alternatively, if this is not enough, you can use cellRenderer. you can see [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for usage